# Devise with different parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise in my rails app, and I have a html version at '/...' and an api at '/api/v#/...' The implementation of devise controllers should be different at '/sign_in' and '/api/v1/sign_in' etc. Also I have an ApiController that all my controllers within the api namespace inherit from.

Basically I need two different sets of devise in my application, each with a different parent class.

I was able to generate the controllers in the api namespace and change the parent of devise to be the ApiController, but that messed up the regular site. That won't work.

I could make a module for my ApiController and then include it in each devise controller... but that seems smelly.

There's only a few features of devise I need within the api so maybe I could just implement them raw without devise. But then I'd lose confirmation functionality and other things.

What do I do?

Let me know what if any code you would like to see.

Comment: By different parent class, you mean two different ActiveModel?

Comment: You can change the class that Devise inherits from. By default it's ApplicationController, but I changed it to ApiController (which inherits from ApplicationController).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify what controllers to use in your routes:

```
devise_for :users # uses the normal devise controllers

namespace :api do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'api/sessions' }
end
```

---

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

That said - creating your own controllers to handle authentication and sessions in an API with Warden (the lower level component of Devise) is pretty simple and is a lot cleaner than shoehorning Devise into doing token based auth or HMAC for example.

Comment: I ended up creating my own authentication with Warden. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @max but wouldn't this still cause Devise to inherit from ApplicationController and all the callbacks defined in application controller will be used in another scope. for e.g API which doesn't need to be inherited from application controller.

Comment: Your controller only inherits from whatever you choose as the superclass. In this example it inherits from `Devise::SessionsController` not `ApplicationController`.

Comment: @max what you are saying is correct, but the issue here is that Api::SessionsController inherits from Devise::SessionsController but Devise itself is getting inherited from ApplicationController 
Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L1,
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L2